# conversion from type 'Stocks' to type integer is not valid in vb.net

Tags: sql, list, vb.net, datatable, dapper

conversion from type 'Stocks' to type integer is not valid in vb.net.

Actually, the code below I use to make a reduction in the "Stocks" table

is there something wrong with my code, please guide me.

There may be something wrong in implementing the code

Thanks

```vb
Private itrservice As New ItemtransfersService()
Private itrservicedetail As New ItemtransfersService()
Private sservice As New Stockservice()

 Private Sub BIBsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BIBsave.Click
            Try
                If grid.RowCount = 0 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Enter Item data item first")
                End If
                Dim obj = New ItemTransfers With {
                    .Invno = BtxtInvoNo.Text,
                    .HeaderInvno = HeaderInvno,
                    .Created = DateTime.Now
                    }
                itrservice.InsertItemTransfers(obj)
                For i = 0 To _myTable.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim detail = New ItemTransfersDetail With {
                        .No = Convert.ToInt32(_myTable.Rows(i)(0)),
                        .Invno = BtxtInvoNo.Text,
                        .CodeProduct = _myTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString(),
                        .Barcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString(),
                        .Colorcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(3).ToString(),
                        .Size = _myTable.Rows(i)(4).ToString(),
                        .Qty = Convert.ToInt32(_myTable.Rows(i)(5).ToString())
                        }
                    itrservicedetail.InsertItemTransfersdetail(detail)
                    Dim getstocks = New Stocks With {
                        .CodeProduct = _myTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString(),
                        .Barcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString(),
                        .Colorcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(3).ToString(),
                        .Size = _myTable.Rows(i)(4).ToString()
                        }
                    Dim GetStock As Integer = sservice.GetStock2(getstocks)
                    Dim stocks = New Stocks With {
                        .QTY_STOCK = Convert.ToInt32((GetStock - detail.Qty)),
                        .CodeProduct = _myTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString(),
                        .Barcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString(),
                        .Colorcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(3).ToString(),
                        .Size = _myTable.Rows(i)(4).ToString()
                        }
                    sservice.Updatestockminus(stocks)
                Next i
                'show success message

                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Item Transfer successfully added")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            End Try
        End Sub
 Public Sub Updatestockminus(ByVal Obj As Stocks)
            Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocks` Set `QTY_STOCK`= {Obj.QTY_STOCK} WHERE `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}' and `BARCODE`='{Obj.Barcode}' and `COLORCODE`='{Obj.Colorcode}' and `SIZE`='{Obj.Size}';"
            Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
                _conn.Execute(sql)
            End Using
        End Sub
        Public Function GetStock2(ByVal Obj As Stocks)
            Dim sql = $"SELECT QTY_STOCK FROM Stocks WHERE `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}' and `BARCODE`='{Obj.Barcode}' and `COLORCODE`='{Obj.Colorcode}' and `SIZE`='{Obj.Size}';"
            Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
                Return _conn.Query(Of Stocks)(sql).FirstOrDefault()
            End Using
        End Function
```

Comment: You have: `Dim GetStock As Integer = sservice.GetStock2(getstocks)`, but that method returns a `Stocks` object, not an Integer -- You should specify the return Type of a Function

Comment: For future reference, please put the language after the three graves when posting code snippets. If you don't do that, it will select the language based on the tags you apply, which are listed in alphabetical order. In this case, that meant that your code snippet was formatted as SQL rather than VB. I have fixed it this time.

Comment: It is very, VERY bad that you have functions with no specified return type. That's terribly lazy programming. You should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties, then fix all the errors that are flagged because you have disregarded data types. You should also turn it `On` in the VS options, so it is `On` by default in all future projects. It will force you to write better code and the compiler will help you do so.

Comment: @Jimi , You mean something like this `Public Function GetStock2(ByVal Obj As Integer) As Stocks`  but if I make it like that then there is an error  `Dim sql = $"SELECT QTY_STOCK FROM Stocks WHERE `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}' and `BARCODE`='{Obj.Barcode}' and `COLORCODE`='{Obj.Colorcode}' and `SIZE`='{Obj.Size}';"` if I make it like that then there is an error `'CodeProduct','Barcode','Colorcode','Size' is not a member of 'Integer' and Value of type 'Stocks' cannot be converted to 'Integer'`

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `. You should also turn it On in the VS options, so it is On by default in all future projects. It will force you to write better code and the compiler will help you do so. ' I have done it but there is an error  `Public Function GetStock2(ByVal Obj As Integer) As Stocks`  but if I make it like that then there is an error .if I make it like that then there is an error `'CodeProduct','Barcode','Colorcode','Size' is not a member of 'Integer' and Value of type 'Stocks' cannot be converted to 'Integer'`

Comment: Of course there's an error. That's the whole point of this question in the first place and Jimi has already told you what the problem is. Why are you declaring the `GetStock` variable as type `Integer` if it's supposed to refer to a `Stocks` object? It should be obvious that it should be type `Stocks`. You might consider using a better name than `GetStock` too, but that's a matter of good practice and won't stop the code working as it should.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , I make like this `Public Function GetStock2(ByVal Obj As Stocks) As Stocks` and  `Dim GetStock = sservice.GetStock2(getstocks)` but error `unable to cast object of type 'Models.Stock' to type system.Iconvertible` please guide me

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question and, as should be obvious, reading code snippets in comments is not something we should have to do. Please edit your question and provide ALL the relevant information and ONLY the relevant information. That includes code, i.e. you provide the absolute minimum code you can to allow us to replicate the issue. Anything that doesn't bear directly on the issue does not belong in the question. If new information becomes relevant, edit the question and add it. You can then add a comment to let us know the question has been updated.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Why are you declaring the GetStock variable as type Integer if it's supposed to refer to a Stocks object?` From your guide then I found a solution. Is the answer from me still there is something that needs to be corrected?

Comment: There are other ways to improve your code but if the answer you posted addresses the issue you asked about then it's a valid answer to the question. This site is all about specific answers to specific questions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `There are other ways to improve your code` Okay I need guidance and improvement from you

Comment: This is not the place for general advice.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution to the problem . This solution was created because of guidance from @jmcilhinney and @jimi

```vb
Private itrservice As New ItemtransfersService()
Private itrservicedetail As New ItemtransfersService()
Private sservice As New Stockservice()

Private Sub BIBsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BIBsave.Click
    Try
        If grid.RowCount = 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Enter Item data item first")
        End If
        Dim obj = New ItemTransfers With {
                    .Invno = BtxtInvoNo.Text,
                    .HeaderInvno = HeaderInvno,
                    .Created = DateTime.Now
                    }
        itrservice.InsertItemTransfers(obj)
        For i = 0 To _myTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim detail = New ItemTransfersDetail With {
                        .No = Convert.ToInt32(_myTable.Rows(i)(0)),
                        .Invno = BtxtInvoNo.Text,
                        .CodeProduct = _myTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString(),
                        .Barcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString(),
                        .Colorcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(3).ToString(),
                        .Size = _myTable.Rows(i)(4).ToString(),
                        .Qty = Convert.ToInt32(_myTable.Rows(i)(5).ToString())
                        }
        itrservicedetail.InsertItemTransfersdetail(detail)
        Dim getstocks = New Stocks With {
                        .CodeProduct = _myTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString(),
                        .Barcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString(),
                        .Colorcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(3).ToString(),
                        .Size = _myTable.Rows(i)(4).ToString()
                        }
        Dim GetStock = sservice.GetStock2(getstocks)
        Dim stocks = New Stocks With {
                        .QTY_STOCK = GetStock.QTY_STOCK - (detail.Qty),
                        .CodeProduct = _myTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString(),
                        .Barcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString(),
                        .Colorcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(3).ToString(),
                        .Size = _myTable.Rows(i)(4).ToString()
                        }
                    sservice.Updatestockminus(stocks)
        Next i
        'show success message
        MessageBox.Show("Transaction Item Transfer successfully added")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub Updatestockminus(ByVal Obj As Stocks)
    Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocks` Set `QTY_STOCK`= {Obj.QTY_STOCK} WHERE `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}' and `BARCODE`='{Obj.Barcode}' and `COLORCODE`='{Obj.Colorcode}' and `SIZE`='{Obj.Size}';"
    Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
         _conn.Execute(sql)
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function GetStock2(ByVal Obj As Stocks) As Stocks
    Dim sql = $"SELECT QTY_STOCK FROM Stocks WHERE `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}' and `BARCODE`='{Obj.Barcode}' and `COLORCODE`='{Obj.Colorcode}' and `SIZE`='{Obj.Size}';"
    Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
        Return _conn.Query(Of Stocks)(sql).FirstOrDefault()
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I see that you completely ignored my comment about specifying the language for your code snippet. If you show us so little respect, you'll soon find people get less willing to help.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Sorry I didn't mean this too thanks to you too I was able to find a solution